# Image fades on hover how to prevent button to do so as well

Tags: html, css, hover

I made a little photo gallery.

When u hover over an image a button should appear in the middle and the image

should fade into the background.

I have this working except for one part:

The button fades with the background which it isn't supposed to.

The button should stay visible on hover.

```css
html {
  background-color: #c3cfe2;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
          flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.container__item {
  background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1525382455947-f319bc05fb35?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1414&q=80");
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 3%;
  margin: 20px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
  transition: opacity 2s;
  -o-object-fit: contain;
     object-fit: contain;
  background-size: contain;
}

.container__button {
  color: white;
  background-color: darkblue;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 30px;
  left: 180px;
  top: 180px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container__item:hover > .container__button {
  opacity: 1;
}

.container__item:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
  }
  .container__item {
    width: 330px;
    height: 330px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .container {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .container__item {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
  }
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>.</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  <div class="container__item"><button class="container__button">hello</button></div>
  
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Button has opacity:0 so it isn't visible unless u hover over the image

The image is declared within  &__item

```
&__item:hover {
opacity: 0.2;
  }

  &__item:hover > &__button {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

Comment: Please share the HTML part also , so that we can help you out correctly

Comment: https://codepen.io/christelva/pen/rNOQGpx Still got loads of things to do, just kinda stuck with the button thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a separate container like this:

`<div class="separate_container">
    <div class="container__item"></div>
    <button class="container__button">hello</button>
  </div>`

In the styles side, `.container_item` takes the image and you can easily manipulate

`.separate_container:hover > .container_button { opacity:1 }`